# I am getting some error at com.codeavenge.calculator.MainActivity.updateTex

Tags: android, android-studio

Today I am tried to make a calculator, but my clear button is throwing error .
`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (5 ... 5) ends beyond length 4`

MainActivity.java looks like this,

```
       binding.clearBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                updateText("");
            }
        });
```

And My activity_main.xml file looks like this,

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:backgroundTint="#FF9800"
                android:text="@string/clear"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                app:cornerRadius="19dp" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you passed an empty string with zero characters in this function **updateText("")**.
There is no text inside the **""** tag. So it will crash because you are trying to setSelection in the editText with character less than **(cursorPosi + 1)** in this line.

```
binding.display.setSelection(cursorPosi + 1);
```

To fix this error you can try calling the function with white space:

```
updateText(" ");
```

But I wonder that you will need to clear all character or detele the character at cursor of the EditText when you click on **clear button**